# Excel 2013 need to count blocks of data filtered by date and agent

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have an absence table where absences are marked with 'A' (you can ignore the H for holidays).

I need to count the number of individual absences for individual agents (e.g. Agent 1, whilst absent for 5 days, this counts as 1 absence, with agent 4 away for 1 day this also counts as 1 absence).

Using Excel 2013.

Any advise gratefully accepted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this formula will work (tested in Excel 2016):
`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:Z2="A",COLUMN(B2:Z2)),IF(B2:Z2<>"A",COLUMN(B2:Z2))),1))`
Modify the column references as necessary.
 You could also use:
`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:Z2=$A$5,COLUMN(B2:Z2)),IF(B2:Z2<>$A$5,COLUMN(B2:Z2))),1))`
since you use A5 to indicate what "A" means.
 This is an array formula, so you have to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after entering the formula. Enter the formula in the first row and then copy/fill down.

This is a modification of the formula I found [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/379415-counting-contiguous-blocks-data.html)
**Edit:** Assuming you have one row for the entire year and the first day of the year is in column D (as in your example), then the formula would be:
`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(D8:ND8=$A$5,COLUMN(D8:ND8)),IF(D8:ND8<>$A$5,COLUMN(D8:ND8))),1))`
or:
`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(D8:ND8="A",COLUMN(D8:ND8)),IF(D8:ND8<>"A",COLUMN(D8:ND8))),1))`
if you would rather just use the character signifying an absence in the formula itself. This formula would go in the same row. Again, this is an array formula, so you have to press SHIFT+CTRL+ENTER for it to work, then fill down for as many rows as you need.

Comment: Thanks, but I can not seem to get this to work. Can you clarify what cell references should be used (or which cell references correspond to which data set)?

Comment: In my example B2:Z2 refers to the range of cells in which you're looking for "A". In your example the range for the first row would be C8:AJ8.  If you place the formula at the end (or beginning, for that matter) of each row, it should work for you. If you want the totals on a separate page, I'd suggest using a column on your example page, hiding it, and then referencing the cells on the totals page to the cells in the hidden column.